# Script to detect and fix Excel data anomalously classed as a date

Tags: microsoft-excel

Genome Biology [recently published](http://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-016-1044-7) results showing that Excel's automatic date formatter caused errors in about 20% of published papers about supplementary gene lists.

> For example, gene symbols such as SEPT2 (Septin 2) and MARCH1 [Membrane-Associated Ring Finger (C3HC4) 1, E3 Ubiquitin Protein Ligase] are converted by default to ‘2-Sep’ and ‘1-Mar’, respectively. Furthermore, RIKEN identifiers were described to be automatically converted to floating point numbers (i.e. from accession ‘2310009E13’ to ‘2.31E+13’)

They [provide bash scripts](https://sourceforge.net/projects/genenameerrorsscreen/) that identify errors based on gene names being converted to dates.

My question is: Is there a generic way to write such a script to parse all my Excel files and detect anomalously formatted data? Can a script reverse these changes? In both cases, what are some things that this script should look for?

Answer (score 1):

Say we are importing data into Excel from some external file.  There are three things at issue:

1. prevent conversion to Date for fields that should be text
2. for data that has already been imported, detect cells that have been erroneously converted to Dates
3. for data that has already been imported, correct the bad cells

The first two steps are straight-forward.  The details of the code depend upon the schema of the data *(which Excel columns need to be processed)*.

The third requires the construction of a translate table that can be used to convert dates back to text.

The translate table is not as bad as it seems *(there can be only 365 entries in the table)*.